# Angular animation

Tags: jquery, animation, angularjs

At the moment I have this line of code right in an ng-click controller

`$(".message").show(300).delay(900).hide(300);`

and while it works absolutely fine I've been told that I must NEVER do animations/jQuery/DOM manipulation from within a controller. Is there another way to do this that doesn't involve a ridiculous amount of messing around?

Comment: Some good animations to angular: [AngularJS Animations](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write a simple directive that watches its attribute:

```
app.directive('animateMe', function() {
   return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.animateMe, function() {
         element.show(300).delay(900).hide(300);
      })
   }
})
```

Put that directive on the HTML element you want to animate.  Have ng-click toggle a model/scope property.

```
<a ng-click="animateToggle = !animateToggle">animate</a>
<div animate-me="animateToggle">...</div>
```

More code, yes.  But now you have something reusable (and you don't need selectors).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/mqVGV/)

In the fiddle, I added ng-hide to the div so that it doesn't appear initially.

---

**Update**:
Angular 1.1.4 now has an [ngAnimate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angAnimate) directive.  Although it is not as flexible as writing your own animation directive, it will handle many scenarios.  The [ng-show](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angShow) (and ng-hide) directive supports the `show` and `hide` [animation methods](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.%24animator#Methods).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use the new ngAnimate directive provided in the AngularJS 1.1.4 Core.

Read more [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html)